# I get an error to insert value in SQL Server 2014 using C# form

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2019

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace LMS
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-IDB5IGO\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LMS;Integrated Security=True");
      
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Std_table(Name,F_Name) VALUES('"+textBox1.Text+","+textBox2.Text+"')";
          
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

Comment: Parameterize your query. String concatenation to produce a SQL statement is the cause of many problems, including this one. You forgot some apostrophes and so you're only passing 1 value for 2 columns. **Parameterize your query.**

Comment: you are missing `'` , change to this instead : `'"+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox2.Text+"'`

Comment: also I agree what @madreflection say, parameterize query is a better option.

Comment: Other issues: connection string should not be hard-coded, connection should definitely *not* be cached, dispose all Sql objects with `using`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments you should be using parameterized queries instead of string concatenation.

You can modify your code like followng.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-IDB5IGO\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LMS;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var sql = "INSERT INTO Std_table(Name,F_Name) VALUES(@Name, @F_Name)";
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = textBox1.Text });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@F_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = textBox2.Text });
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @DanGuzman says: Can we stop using [AddWithValue](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) already?

Comment: @Charlieface, thanks for the suggestion, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Did you mean `.Value` not `{ Value ...`?

Comment: I take it you haven't actually read that article. `AddWithValue` also has an issue with `MaxLen` it sets it to whatever the value is. So instead do: `, SqlDbType.VarChar, 10)` or whatever. @CaiusJard Either works

Comment: @Charlieface though note that plenty of people (here included) climb on the "down with addwithvalue" bandwagon while failing to note that it isn't universally applicable to all databases; MySQL actively promote it..

Comment: @CaiusJard Is that so? I have little experience with MySQL and none with any other. I would imagine the principle is the same: `AddWithValue` guesses data-types and often gets it wrong, ergo the indexes are not used correctly. I would love to hear more

Comment: @Charlieface hah, I skipped the `new` and read it as `parameters.Add("@x", Varchar) { Value = ...` - was thinking I'd missed some cute syntax for years. More coffee..

Comment: @charlieface see https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/using-addwithvalue/ (I also tend to let people off for using AWV for sprocs, inserts etc.. I figure it's more important that they're parameterizing badly than concatenating :D )

Comment: @CaiusJard Interesting. I think that says more about the quality of MySQL (or lack...) than about Dan Guzman, to be honest. Agreed on your last point.